Spring embedding graph layout with some rigid edges
Is it possible to specify GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding" or GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding" but with some rigid edges?
I want the blue edges to be rigid, i.e. to hold the shapes of right angled triangle and isosceles trapezoid. To the red edges the spring layout should be applied.
On the first image we have starting position, the second one is with "SpringEmbedding" (applied to the whole graph, i.e. shapes of the triangle and the trapezoid have changed).
The third image depicts how "SpringEmbedding" with some rigid edges might have looked.
gr = Graph[
  Range[7], {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 
    7}, {6, 7}, {4, 5}}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0.2}, {2, 
     0.8}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}}, 
  EdgeStyle -> 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 | 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> Red, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]

AnnotationValue[gr, VertexCoordinates] = Automatic;
AnnotationValue[gr, GraphLayout] = "SpringEmbedding";
gr

AnnotationValue[gr, VertexCoordinates] = 
  Join[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 
     1}}, (RotationMatrix[-0.9] . (# - {5/2, 0.5`})) + {5/2, 
       0.5`} & /@ {{2, 0.2}, {2, 0.8}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}}];
gr




If I understand correctly, you want to change the shape of the graph keeping fixed the relative position of specified vertices --- as if they constituted the vertices of a rigid polygonal tile.
Changing the edge-weight might be a good idea and should work for triangle tiles, but it becomes difficult to keep the shape of trapezoid, or more general $k$-gons with $k\geq 4$.
So I gave up using build-in vertex layout algorithm, and wrote a code from scratch.
Let $\{v_{1}, v_{2}, \cdots, v_{k}\}$ be the vertices of a $k$-gon in the graph.
Usual graph embedding algorithm assume that these $k$ points can move freely in the 2D plane. But we want the shape of this $k$-gon is fixed. So the motion of $v_{1}, v_{2}, \cdots, v_{k}$ are subject to a single geometric transformation --- rotation by angle $\theta$ followed by translation by vector $(x,y)$. So energy function of vertex configuration can be expressed in terms of these rigid-motion parameters as well as the usual coordinates of the free vertices, if any.
Efficiency was not considered in the following code, but it should work on not-too-large graphs. Please adjust the value of springConstant and naturalSpringLength  to your liking.
ClearAll[reshape]; 
reshape[gr_Graph, constrainedVertices_List] := 
 Module[{freeVertices, initialVertexCoordinates, n, m, 
   tentativeVertexCoordinates, vars, springConstant, 
   naturalSpringLength, energy, ans, newVertexCoordinates, th, x, y},
  freeVertices = Complement[VertexList[gr], Flatten[constrainedVertices]]; 
  initialVertexCoordinates = Thread[VertexList[gr] -> GraphEmbedding[gr]];
  n = Length[constrainedVertices]; 
  m = Length[freeVertices]; 
  tentativeVertexCoordinates = 
   Sort[Flatten[{
    Table[#->TranslationTransform[{x[i],y[i]}][RotationTransform[th[i]][#/. 
             initialVertexCoordinates]] & /@ 
        constrainedVertices[[i]], {i, n}],
      Table[freeVertices[[i]]->{x[n+i],y[n+i]},{i,1,m}]}]];
  (* variables and their initial values *)
  vars = Flatten[{Table[{{x[i],0},{y[i],0},{th[i],0}},{i,1,n}],
     Table[{{x[n+i],(freeVertices[[i]]/.initialVertexCoordinates)[[1]]},
            {y[n+i],(freeVertices[[i]]/.initialVertexCoordinates)[[1]]}}, 
    {i, 1, m}]}, 2]; 
  springConstant = 3.0; (* strength of attractive force *)
  naturalSpringLength = 1.0;
  energy = (
    (* repulsive potential to prevent vertices from getting too close *)
    Total[1/EuclideanDistance @@ (# /. tentativeVertexCoordinates) & /@
         Subsets[VertexList[gr], {2}]] +
    (* attractive spring potential *)
    springConstant * Sum[
      ((EuclideanDistance @@ (List @@ e /. tentativeVertexCoordinates)) - 
           naturalSpringLength)^2, {e, EdgeList[gr]}] /. Abs->Identity); 
  (* find a configuration that minimizes energy *)
  ans = FindMinimum[energy, vars];
  newVertexCoordinates = tentativeVertexCoordinates /. ans[[2]]; 
  Graph[gr, VertexCoordinates -> newVertexCoordinates]
  ];

Your original graph:
gr = Graph[
  Range[7], {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 
    7}, {6, 7}, {4, 5}}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0.2}, {2, 
     0.8}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}}, 
  EdgeStyle -> 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 | 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> Red, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]


constrainedVertices is a list of vertices of rigid polygons (the right-angled triangle and the isosceles trapezoid)
constrainedVertices = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 6, 7, 5}};

reshape[gr, constrainedVertices]


Another sample graph:
gr2 = EdgeAdd[gr, {1 <-> 8, 8 <-> 6}]


reshape[gr2, constrainedVertices]



Can you post also the version with weighted edges when there are only rigid triangles? In case you have already the code.

Sorry, I don't have such codes. I made a quick decision that by using the option GraphLayout -> {"SpringEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True}, we can change the spring constants, namely $k_{ij}$'s in the tutorial, "Introduction to Graph Drawing / the Graph Drawing Algorithms / Spring Embedding". If so, by assigning very large values to them, we can effectively freeze the edge lengths. But I was wrong. I found that edge weights are used not as spring constants, but just as stretching factors of edge lengths.
